# Run Java Molecular Dynamic simulation program in multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, applet

I have this applet here that I have to make it work in multithreads. I try to, but its seems when set the number of threads at 1, the program runs as expected. So, generally the program runs ok. But if I set the value lets say 2 or 4. Is getting crazy. Im not getting the required outcome. It seems that is something wrong with the calculations. Im banging my head on the wall, trying to figure out whats wrong but, everything I tried, seems to not solve the problem. Heres is the sequential code:

```
/*
 * "Physics" part of code adapted from Dan Schroeder's applet at:
 *
 *     http://physics.weber.edu/schroeder/software/mdapplet.html
 */

import java.awt.* ;
import javax.swing.* ;

public class MD {

    // Size of simulation

    final static int N = 2000 ;   // Number of "atoms"
    final static double BOX_WIDTH = 100.0 ;


    // Initial state - controls temperature of system

    //final static double VELOCITY = 3.0 ;  // gaseous
    final static double VELOCITY = 2.0 ;  // gaseous/"liquid"
    //final static double VELOCITY = 1.0 ;  // "crystalline"

    final static double INIT_SEPARATION = 2.2 ;  // in atomic radii


    // Simulation

    final static double DT = 0.01 ;  // Time step


    // Display

    final static int WINDOW_SIZE = 800 ;
    final static int DELAY = 0 ;
    final static int OUTPUT_FREQ = 20 ;


    // Physics constants

    final static double ATOM_RADIUS = 0.5 ;

    final static double WALL_STIFFNESS = 500.0 ;
    final static double GRAVITY = 0.005 ;
    final static double FORCE_CUTOFF = 3.0 ;


    // Atom positions
    static double [] x = new double [N] ;
    static double [] y = new double [N] ;

    // Atom velocities
    static double [] vx = new double [N] ;
    static double [] vy = new double [N] ;

    // Atom accelerations
    static double [] ax = new double [N] ;
    static double [] ay = new double [N] ;


    public static void main(String args []) throws Exception {

        Display display = new Display() ;

        // Define initial state of atoms

        int sqrtN = (int) (Math.sqrt((double) N) + 0.5) ;
        double initSeparation = INIT_SEPARATION * ATOM_RADIUS ;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) {
            // lay out atoms regularly, so no overlap
            x [i] = (0.5 + i % sqrtN) * initSeparation ;
            y [i] = (0.5 + i / sqrtN) * initSeparation ;
            vx [i] = (2 * Math.random() - 1) * VELOCITY ;
            vy [i] = (2 * Math.random() - 1) * VELOCITY ;
        } 

        int iter = 0 ;
        while(true) {

            if(iter % OUTPUT_FREQ == 0) {
                System.out.println("iter = " + iter + ", time = " + iter * DT) ;
                display.repaint() ;
                Thread.sleep(DELAY) ;
            }

            // Verlet integration:
            // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration#Velocity_Verlet

            double dtOver2 = 0.5 * DT;
            double dtSquaredOver2 = 0.5 * DT * DT;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                x[i] += (vx[i] * DT) + (ax[i] * dtSquaredOver2);
                        // update position
                y[i] += (vy[i] * DT) + (ay[i] * dtSquaredOver2);
                vx[i] += (ax[i] * dtOver2);  // update velocity halfway
                vy[i] += (ay[i] * dtOver2);
            }

            computeAccelerations();

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                vx[i] += (ax[i] * dtOver2);
                        // finish updating velocity with new acceleration
                vy[i] += (ay[i] * dtOver2);
            }

            iter++ ;
        }
    }

    // Compute accelerations of all atoms from current positions:
    static void computeAccelerations() {

        double dx, dy;  // separations in x and y directions
        double dx2, dy2, rSquared, rSquaredInv, attract, repel, fOverR, fx, fy;

        // first check for bounces off walls, and include gravity (if any):
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (x[i] < ATOM_RADIUS) {
                ax[i] = WALL_STIFFNESS * (ATOM_RADIUS - x[i]);
            }
            else if (x[i] > (BOX_WIDTH - ATOM_RADIUS)) {
                ax[i] = WALL_STIFFNESS * (BOX_WIDTH - ATOM_RADIUS - x[i]);
            }
            else {
                ax[i] = 0.0;
            }
            if (y[i] < ATOM_RADIUS) {
                ay[i] = (WALL_STIFFNESS * (ATOM_RADIUS - y[i]));
            }
            else if (y[i] > (BOX_WIDTH - ATOM_RADIUS)) {
                ay[i] = (WALL_STIFFNESS * (BOX_WIDTH - ATOM_RADIUS - y[i]));
            }
            else {
                ay[i] = 0;
            }
            ay[i] -= GRAVITY ;
        }

        double forceCutoff2 = FORCE_CUTOFF * FORCE_CUTOFF ;

        // Now compute interaction forces (Lennard-Jones potential).
        // This is where the program spends most of its time.


        for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {           // loop over all distinct pairs
                dx = x[i] - x[j];
                dx2 = dx * dx;
                if (dx2 < forceCutoff2) {               // make sure they're close enough to bother
                    dy = y[i] - y[j];
                    dy2 = dy * dy;
                    if (dy2 < forceCutoff2) {
                        rSquared = dx2 + dy2;
                        if (rSquared < forceCutoff2) {
                            rSquaredInv = 1.0 / rSquared;
                            attract = rSquaredInv * rSquaredInv * rSquaredInv;
                            repel = attract * attract;
                            fOverR = 24.0 * ((2.0 * repel) - attract) * rSquaredInv;
                            fx = fOverR * dx;
                            fy = fOverR * dy;
                            ax[i] += fx;  // add this force on to i's acceleration (mass = 1)
                            ay[i] += fy;

                            ax[j] -= fx;  // Newton's 3rd law
                            ay[j] -= fy;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    static class Display extends JPanel {

        static final double SCALE = WINDOW_SIZE / BOX_WIDTH ;

        static final int DIAMETER =
                Math.max((int) (SCALE * 2 * ATOM_RADIUS), 2) ;

        Display() {

            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WINDOW_SIZE, WINDOW_SIZE)) ;

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("MD");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setContentPane(this);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE) ;
            g.fillRect(0, 0, WINDOW_SIZE, WINDOW_SIZE) ;
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE) ;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) {
                g.fillOval((int) (SCALE * (x [i] - ATOM_RADIUS)),
                           WINDOW_SIZE - 1 - (int) (SCALE * (y [i] + ATOM_RADIUS)),
                           DIAMETER, DIAMETER) ;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody spot whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`begin` and `end` are declared as static so all the threads are wrongly using the same variables during their computation.

A) The begin/end will be mistakenly set to some random output of the race conditions between the threads at the begining of their method run()

B) All threads will potentially work on the same indexes range ignoring rest of the position, velocity, acceleration arrays.

Also all threads are running uncessary exactly the same code:

```
           for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                x[i] += (vx[i] * DT) + (ax[i] * dtSquaredOver2);
                // update position
            ...
```

I would recommend changing all the variables to instance variables, and then going through the code modified to static only those which should be shared between the threads. Reads of the static variable are fine, the writes have to be checked if they are exclusive. (Writing to different parts of your x, vx... arrays are 'exclusive' in that sense, just make sure that indexes do not overlap).

Comment: Well spotted.  I remove static from end and begin. And use them on the loop you mentioned. Its working now. Thanks Zielu